# NumPy row operations that depend on other rows/columns

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting, elementwise-operations

### Problem

I am trying to avoid a for loop in NumPy (which is quite messy and obviously performance prohibiting). My challenge is that operations on each row depend on other rows. That is:

I have a (very large) array with 8 columns. In each row I need to find the indices of the 2 (or some arbitrary number N) rows whose values in the first column are closest (to the first column of the current row) while ensuring that the values in the second column and fourth column are identical (across all 3 rows).

### Desired Output

So, I should end up with an array that is the same length as my large initial array by 2 (or N) where each row contains the indices of the other rows in the "master" array that meet the conditions above.

### Current Attempt

In my original for-loop I was broadcasting because I had filtered my array to be small enough to do so.

My attempt is now as follows:

```
def query_trks(self, FULL, trk, t, v, N):
    filt = np.where((FULL[:,1]==t, FULL[:,4]==v))[0]
    trks = FULL[filt, 0]
    idxs = np.abs(trks[:, None] - trks).argsort(axis=0)[:N]
    return idxs.T.astype(int)        

def create_idxs(self, DATA):
    self.query_trks(DATA, DATA[:,0], DATA[:,1], DATA[:,4], 3)
```

I think I might still be able to broadcast but my issue is basically getting a filtered array (for the second and fourth columns) for each row of the "master" array. Right now, the entire length of the array is returned because of the elementwise comparison.

How can I obtain the desired output? Am I on the right track at least?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Below is a minimized example of the "master" array with the farthest right column depicting the pattern for the desired output.

```
1.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.39604e+03 0.00000e+00 1.59155e-02 0.00000e+00 [27, 54]
1.00000e+00 1.00000e+00 -1.63687e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.39753e+03 0.00000e+00 1.59280e-02 2.03148e-06 [29, 55]
1.00000e+00 2.00000e+00 -1.63639e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.40051e+03 0.00000e+00 1.59406e-02 6.77694e-07 [30, 56]
1.00000e+00 3.00000e+00 -1.63567e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.40497e+03 0.00000e+00 1.59532e-02 3.39114e-07 [31, 57]
1.00000e+00 4.00000e+00 -1.63471e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.41093e+03 0.00000e+00 1.59658e-02 2.03629e-07   ...
1.00000e+00 5.00000e+00 -1.63350e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.41839e+03 0.00000e+00 1.59784e-02 1.35860e-07
1.00000e+00 6.00000e+00 -1.63206e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.42735e+03 0.00000e+00 1.59910e-02 9.71192e-08
1.00000e+00 7.00000e+00 -1.63036e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.43783e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60036e-02 7.28968e-08
1.00000e+00 8.00000e+00 -1.62842e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.44982e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60162e-02 5.67421e-08
1.00000e+00 9.00000e+00 -1.62622e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.46335e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60288e-02 4.54294e-08
1.00000e+00 1.00000e+01 -1.62376e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.47842e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60415e-02 3.71987e-08
1.00000e+00 1.10000e+01 -1.62104e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.49505e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60541e-02 3.10231e-08
1.00000e+00 1.20000e+01 -1.61806e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.51325e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60668e-02 2.62708e-08
1.00000e+00 1.30000e+01 -1.61481e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.53305e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60795e-02 2.25354e-08
1.00000e+00 1.40000e+01 -1.61127e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.55445e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60922e-02 1.95458e-08
1.00000e+00 1.50000e+01 -1.60746e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.57748e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61049e-02 1.71157e-08
1.00000e+00 1.60000e+01 -1.60336e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.60216e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61176e-02 1.51137e-08
1.00000e+00 1.70000e+01 -1.59895e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.62851e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61303e-02 1.34446e-08
1.00000e+00 1.80000e+01 -1.59425e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.65658e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61430e-02 1.20385e-08
1.00000e+00 1.90000e+01 -1.58923e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.68637e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61557e-02 1.08427e-08
1.00000e+00 2.00000e+01 -1.58389e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.71794e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61685e-02 9.81735e-09
1.00000e+00 2.10000e+01 -1.57822e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.75130e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61812e-02 8.93139e-09
1.00000e+00 2.20000e+01 -1.57220e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.78651e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61940e-02 8.16063e-09
1.00000e+00 2.30000e+01 -1.56584e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.82360e+03 0.00000e+00 1.62068e-02 7.48589e-09
1.00000e+00 2.40000e+01 -1.55911e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.86261e+03 0.00000e+00 1.62196e-02 6.89183e-09
1.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 -1.55200e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 2.90361e+03 0.00000e+00 1.62324e-02 6.36604e-09
1.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 nan nan 2.39604e+03 nan nan nan 6.36604e-09
2.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 1.69426e+03 1.69426e+03 1.59155e-02 0.00000e+00 [0, 54]
2.00000e+00 1.00000e+00 -1.63694e+07 1.69426e+03 2.39604e+03 1.69575e+03 1.69426e+03 1.59280e-02 2.03148e-06 [1, 55]
2.00000e+00 2.00000e+00 -1.63660e+07 5.08278e+03 2.39604e+03 1.69872e+03 1.69426e+03 1.59406e-02 6.77694e-07 [2, 56]
2.00000e+00 3.00000e+00 -1.63609e+07 1.01656e+04 2.39604e+03 1.70319e+03 1.69426e+03 1.59532e-02 3.39114e-07 [3, 57]
2.00000e+00 4.00000e+00 -1.63541e+07 1.69426e+04 2.39604e+03 1.70914e+03 1.69425e+03 1.59658e-02 2.03629e-07   ...
2.00000e+00 5.00000e+00 -1.63456e+07 2.54139e+04 2.39604e+03 1.71659e+03 1.69425e+03 1.59784e-02 1.35860e-07
2.00000e+00 6.00000e+00 -1.63353e+07 3.55794e+04 2.39604e+03 1.72554e+03 1.69423e+03 1.59910e-02 9.71192e-08
2.00000e+00 7.00000e+00 -1.63233e+07 4.74391e+04 2.39604e+03 1.73600e+03 1.69421e+03 1.60036e-02 7.28968e-08
2.00000e+00 8.00000e+00 -1.63094e+07 6.09929e+04 2.39604e+03 1.74797e+03 1.69417e+03 1.60162e-02 5.67421e-08
2.00000e+00 9.00000e+00 -1.62937e+07 7.62407e+04 2.39604e+03 1.76145e+03 1.69412e+03 1.60288e-02 4.54294e-08
2.00000e+00 1.00000e+01 -1.62762e+07 9.31823e+04 2.39604e+03 1.77647e+03 1.69405e+03 1.60415e-02 3.71987e-08
2.00000e+00 1.10000e+01 -1.62568e+07 1.11817e+05 2.39604e+03 1.79302e+03 1.69396e+03 1.60541e-02 3.10231e-08
2.00000e+00 1.20000e+01 -1.62353e+07 1.32146e+05 2.39604e+03 1.81111e+03 1.69383e+03 1.60668e-02 2.62708e-08
2.00000e+00 1.30000e+01 -1.62119e+07 1.54167e+05 2.39604e+03 1.83077e+03 1.69367e+03 1.60795e-02 2.25354e-08
2.00000e+00 1.40000e+01 -1.61864e+07 1.77879e+05 2.39604e+03 1.85200e+03 1.69347e+03 1.60922e-02 1.95458e-08
2.00000e+00 1.50000e+01 -1.61588e+07 2.03283e+05 2.39604e+03 1.87481e+03 1.69322e+03 1.61049e-02 1.71157e-08
2.00000e+00 1.60000e+01 -1.61290e+07 2.30377e+05 2.39604e+03 1.89923e+03 1.69291e+03 1.61176e-02 1.51137e-08
2.00000e+00 1.70000e+01 -1.60970e+07 2.59160e+05 2.39604e+03 1.92527e+03 1.69254e+03 1.61303e-02 1.34446e-08
2.00000e+00 1.80000e+01 -1.60626e+07 2.89630e+05 2.39604e+03 1.95295e+03 1.69210e+03 1.61430e-02 1.20385e-08
2.00000e+00 1.90000e+01 -1.60257e+07 3.21785e+05 2.39604e+03 1.98229e+03 1.69157e+03 1.61557e-02 1.08427e-08
2.00000e+00 2.00000e+01 -1.59864e+07 3.55622e+05 2.39604e+03 2.01331e+03 1.69095e+03 1.61685e-02 9.81735e-09
2.00000e+00 2.10000e+01 -1.59445e+07 3.91140e+05 2.39604e+03 2.04604e+03 1.69022e+03 1.61812e-02 8.93139e-09
2.00000e+00 2.20000e+01 -1.58998e+07 4.28334e+05 2.39604e+03 2.08050e+03 1.68937e+03 1.61940e-02 8.16063e-09
2.00000e+00 2.30000e+01 -1.58524e+07 4.67201e+05 2.39604e+03 2.11672e+03 1.68840e+03 1.62068e-02 7.48589e-09
2.00000e+00 2.40000e+01 -1.58021e+07 5.07736e+05 2.39604e+03 2.15474e+03 1.68728e+03 1.62196e-02 6.89183e-09
2.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 -1.57487e+07 5.49934e+05 2.39604e+03 2.19459e+03 1.68600e+03 1.62324e-02 6.36604e-09
2.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 nan nan 2.39604e+03 nan nan nan 6.36604e-09
3.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 1.46715e-13 2.39604e+03 1.59155e-02 0.00000e+00
3.00000e+00 1.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 2.39604e+03 2.39604e+03 1.48721e+00 2.39604e+03 1.59280e-02 2.03148e-06
3.00000e+00 2.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 7.18813e+03 2.39604e+03 4.46162e+00 2.39604e+03 1.59406e-02 6.77694e-07
3.00000e+00 3.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 1.43763e+04 2.39604e+03 8.92324e+00 2.39604e+03 1.59532e-02 3.39114e-07
3.00000e+00 4.00000e+00 -1.63710e+07 2.39604e+04 2.39604e+03 1.48721e+01 2.39604e+03 1.59658e-02 2.03629e-07
3.00000e+00 5.00000e+00 -1.63710e+07 3.59407e+04 2.39604e+03 2.23081e+01 2.39603e+03 1.59784e-02 1.35860e-07
3.00000e+00 6.00000e+00 -1.63709e+07 5.03169e+04 2.39604e+03 3.12314e+01 2.39601e+03 1.59910e-02 9.71191e-08
3.00000e+00 7.00000e+00 -1.63707e+07 6.70890e+04 2.39604e+03 4.16419e+01 2.39597e+03 1.60036e-02 7.28965e-08
3.00000e+00 8.00000e+00 -1.63704e+07 8.62570e+04 2.39604e+03 5.35398e+01 2.39593e+03 1.60162e-02 5.67417e-08
3.00000e+00 9.00000e+00 -1.63700e+07 1.07821e+05 2.39604e+03 6.69252e+01 2.39585e+03 1.60288e-02 4.54288e-08
3.00000e+00 1.00000e+01 -1.63694e+07 1.31780e+05 2.39604e+03 8.17983e+01 2.39576e+03 1.60415e-02 3.71979e-08
3.00000e+00 1.10000e+01 -1.63686e+07 1.58134e+05 2.39604e+03 9.81593e+01 2.39563e+03 1.60541e-02 3.10222e-08
3.00000e+00 1.20000e+01 -1.63675e+07 1.86882e+05 2.39604e+03 1.16009e+02 2.39545e+03 1.60668e-02 2.62696e-08
3.00000e+00 1.30000e+01 -1.63661e+07 2.18025e+05 2.39604e+03 1.35347e+02 2.39523e+03 1.60795e-02 2.25338e-08
3.00000e+00 1.40000e+01 -1.63644e+07 2.51560e+05 2.39604e+03 1.56175e+02 2.39495e+03 1.60922e-02 1.95439e-08
3.00000e+00 1.50000e+01 -1.63622e+07 2.87487e+05 2.39604e+03 1.78493e+02 2.39461e+03 1.61049e-02 1.71135e-08
3.00000e+00 1.60000e+01 -1.63595e+07 3.25804e+05 2.39604e+03 2.02303e+02 2.39419e+03 1.61176e-02 1.51111e-08
3.00000e+00 1.70000e+01 -1.63563e+07 3.66509e+05 2.39604e+03 2.27607e+02 2.39369e+03 1.61303e-02 1.34416e-08
3.00000e+00 1.80000e+01 -1.63525e+07 4.09601e+05 2.39604e+03 2.54404e+02 2.39309e+03 1.61430e-02 1.20350e-08
3.00000e+00 1.90000e+01 -1.63479e+07 4.55077e+05 2.39604e+03 2.82699e+02 2.39238e+03 1.61557e-02 1.08388e-08
3.00000e+00 2.00000e+01 -1.63425e+07 5.02932e+05 2.39604e+03 3.12493e+02 2.39155e+03 1.61685e-02 9.81292e-09
3.00000e+00 2.10000e+01 -1.63363e+07 5.53165e+05 2.39604e+03 3.43789e+02 2.39059e+03 1.61812e-02 8.92644e-09
3.00000e+00 2.20000e+01 -1.63291e+07 6.05770e+05 2.39604e+03 3.76590e+02 2.38948e+03 1.61940e-02 8.15512e-09
3.00000e+00 2.30000e+01 -1.63208e+07 6.60743e+05 2.39604e+03 4.10901e+02 2.38820e+03 1.62068e-02 7.47980e-09
3.00000e+00 2.40000e+01 -1.63114e+07 7.18077e+05 2.39604e+03 4.46726e+02 2.38675e+03 1.62196e-02 6.88512e-09
3.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 -1.63007e+07 7.77767e+05 2.39604e+03 4.84070e+02 2.38511e+03 1.62324e-02 6.35869e-09
3.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 nan nan 2.39604e+03 nan nan nan 6.35869e-09
4.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 -1.69426e+03 1.69426e+03 1.59155e-02 0.00000e+00
4.00000e+00 1.00000e+00 -1.63728e+07 1.69426e+03 2.39604e+03 -1.69277e+03 1.69426e+03 1.59280e-02 2.03148e-06
4.00000e+00 2.00000e+00 -1.63762e+07 5.08278e+03 2.39604e+03 -1.68980e+03 1.69426e+03 1.59406e-02 6.77694e-07
4.00000e+00 3.00000e+00 -1.63812e+07 1.01656e+04 2.39604e+03 -1.68534e+03 1.69426e+03 1.59532e-02 3.39114e-07
4.00000e+00 4.00000e+00 -1.63880e+07 1.69426e+04 2.39604e+03 -1.67940e+03 1.69425e+03 1.59658e-02 2.03629e-07
4.00000e+00 5.00000e+00 -1.63964e+07 2.54139e+04 2.39604e+03 -1.67198e+03 1.69425e+03 1.59784e-02 1.35860e-07
4.00000e+00 6.00000e+00 -1.64065e+07 3.55794e+04 2.39604e+03 -1.66308e+03 1.69423e+03 1.59910e-02 9.71192e-08
4.00000e+00 7.00000e+00 -1.64181e+07 4.74391e+04 2.39604e+03 -1.65272e+03 1.69421e+03 1.60036e-02 7.28968e-08
4.00000e+00 8.00000e+00 -1.64314e+07 6.09929e+04 2.39604e+03 -1.64089e+03 1.69418e+03 1.60162e-02 5.67421e-08
4.00000e+00 9.00000e+00 -1.64462e+07 7.62407e+04 2.39604e+03 -1.62760e+03 1.69413e+03 1.60288e-02 4.54294e-08
4.00000e+00 1.00000e+01 -1.64626e+07 9.31823e+04 2.39604e+03 -1.61286e+03 1.69406e+03 1.60415e-02 3.71987e-08
4.00000e+00 1.10000e+01 -1.64804e+07 1.11817e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.59669e+03 1.69397e+03 1.60541e-02 3.10232e-08
4.00000e+00 1.20000e+01 -1.64997e+07 1.32146e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.57908e+03 1.69385e+03 1.60668e-02 2.62709e-08
4.00000e+00 1.30000e+01 -1.65203e+07 1.54167e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.56005e+03 1.69369e+03 1.60795e-02 2.25354e-08
4.00000e+00 1.40000e+01 -1.65423e+07 1.77880e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.53960e+03 1.69350e+03 1.60922e-02 1.95458e-08
4.00000e+00 1.50000e+01 -1.65656e+07 2.03284e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.51776e+03 1.69327e+03 1.61049e-02 1.71158e-08
4.00000e+00 1.60000e+01 -1.65900e+07 2.30379e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.49452e+03 1.69298e+03 1.61176e-02 1.51138e-08
4.00000e+00 1.70000e+01 -1.66157e+07 2.59162e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.46991e+03 1.69264e+03 1.61303e-02 1.34447e-08
4.00000e+00 1.80000e+01 -1.66424e+07 2.89634e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.44393e+03 1.69224e+03 1.61430e-02 1.20386e-08
4.00000e+00 1.90000e+01 -1.66700e+07 3.21791e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.41660e+03 1.69176e+03 1.61557e-02 1.08428e-08
4.00000e+00 2.00000e+01 -1.66987e+07 3.55631e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.38793e+03 1.69121e+03 1.61685e-02 9.81749e-09
4.00000e+00 2.10000e+01 -1.67281e+07 3.91153e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.35793e+03 1.69057e+03 1.61812e-02 8.93157e-09
4.00000e+00 2.20000e+01 -1.67583e+07 4.28354e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.32662e+03 1.68984e+03 1.61940e-02 8.16085e-09
4.00000e+00 2.30000e+01 -1.67892e+07 4.67230e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.29401e+03 1.68900e+03 1.62068e-02 7.48616e-09
4.00000e+00 2.40000e+01 -1.68207e+07 5.07777e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.26011e+03 1.68806e+03 1.62196e-02 6.89215e-09
4.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 -1.68526e+07 5.49992e+05 2.39604e+03 -1.22494e+03 1.68700e+03 1.62324e-02 6.36643e-09
4.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 nan nan 2.39604e+03 nan nan nan 6.36643e-09
5.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 0.00000e+00 2.39604e+03 -2.39604e+03 2.93431e-13 1.59155e-02 0.00000e+00
5.00000e+00 1.00000e+00 -1.63735e+07 2.93431e-13 2.39604e+03 -2.39456e+03 2.93431e-13 1.59280e-02 2.03148e-06
5.00000e+00 2.00000e+00 -1.63783e+07 8.80292e-13 2.39604e+03 -2.39158e+03 2.93431e-13 1.59406e-02 6.77694e-07
5.00000e+00 3.00000e+00 -1.63854e+07 1.76058e-12 2.39604e+03 -2.38713e+03 2.93430e-13 1.59532e-02 3.39114e-07
5.00000e+00 4.00000e+00 -1.63950e+07 2.93431e-12 2.39604e+03 -2.38119e+03 2.93430e-13 1.59658e-02 2.03629e-07
5.00000e+00 5.00000e+00 -1.64069e+07 4.40146e-12 2.39604e+03 -2.37377e+03 2.93429e-13 1.59784e-02 1.35860e-07
5.00000e+00 6.00000e+00 -1.64212e+07 6.16204e-12 2.39604e+03 -2.36489e+03 2.93426e-13 1.59910e-02 9.71192e-08
5.00000e+00 7.00000e+00 -1.64378e+07 8.21604e-12 2.39604e+03 -2.35454e+03 2.93422e-13 1.60036e-02 7.28968e-08
5.00000e+00 8.00000e+00 -1.64567e+07 1.05634e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.34274e+03 2.93416e-13 1.60162e-02 5.67421e-08
5.00000e+00 9.00000e+00 -1.64778e+07 1.32042e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.32949e+03 2.93408e-13 1.60288e-02 4.54294e-08
5.00000e+00 1.00000e+01 -1.65012e+07 1.61384e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.31481e+03 2.93396e-13 1.60415e-02 3.71987e-08
5.00000e+00 1.10000e+01 -1.65267e+07 1.93658e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.29871e+03 2.93380e-13 1.60541e-02 3.10232e-08
5.00000e+00 1.20000e+01 -1.65544e+07 2.28865e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.28120e+03 2.93360e-13 1.60668e-02 2.62709e-08
5.00000e+00 1.30000e+01 -1.65842e+07 2.67003e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.26229e+03 2.93334e-13 1.60795e-02 2.25354e-08
5.00000e+00 1.40000e+01 -1.66160e+07 3.08072e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.24200e+03 2.93301e-13 1.60922e-02 1.95458e-08
5.00000e+00 1.50000e+01 -1.66498e+07 3.52071e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.22035e+03 2.93261e-13 1.61049e-02 1.71158e-08
5.00000e+00 1.60000e+01 -1.66855e+07 3.98996e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.19734e+03 2.93212e-13 1.61176e-02 1.51138e-08
5.00000e+00 1.70000e+01 -1.67231e+07 4.48847e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.17300e+03 2.93154e-13 1.61303e-02 1.34447e-08
5.00000e+00 1.80000e+01 -1.67624e+07 5.01621e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.14735e+03 2.93085e-13 1.61430e-02 1.20386e-08
5.00000e+00 1.90000e+01 -1.68035e+07 5.57315e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.12040e+03 2.93005e-13 1.61557e-02 1.08428e-08
5.00000e+00 2.00000e+01 -1.68462e+07 6.15925e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.09216e+03 2.92911e-13 1.61685e-02 9.81749e-09
5.00000e+00 2.10000e+01 -1.68904e+07 6.77448e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.06267e+03 2.92803e-13 1.61812e-02 8.93157e-09
5.00000e+00 2.20000e+01 -1.69361e+07 7.41878e-11 2.39604e+03 -2.03193e+03 2.92680e-13 1.61940e-02 8.16085e-09
5.00000e+00 2.30000e+01 -1.69832e+07 8.09211e-11 2.39604e+03 -1.99997e+03 2.92540e-13 1.62068e-02 7.48616e-09
5.00000e+00 2.40000e+01 -1.70316e+07 8.79439e-11 2.39604e+03 -1.96680e+03 2.92382e-13 1.62196e-02 6.89215e-09
5.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 -1.70812e+07 9.52557e-11 2.39604e+03 -1.93245e+03 2.92204e-13 1.62324e-02 6.36643e-09
5.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 nan nan 2.39604e+03 nan nan nan 6.36643e-09
6.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.32003e+03 0.00000e+00 1.59155e-02 0.00000e+00 [162, 189]
6.00000e+00 1.00000e+00 -1.63638e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.32152e+03 0.00000e+00 1.59280e-02 6.64958e-07 [163, 190]
6.00000e+00 2.00000e+00 -1.63491e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.32449e+03 0.00000e+00 1.59406e-02 2.21828e-07 [164, 191]
6.00000e+00 3.00000e+00 -1.63271e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.32897e+03 0.00000e+00 1.59532e-02 1.11001e-07 [165, 192]
6.00000e+00 4.00000e+00 -1.62978e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.33495e+03 0.00000e+00 1.59658e-02 6.66533e-08     ...
6.00000e+00 5.00000e+00 -1.62612e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.34245e+03 0.00000e+00 1.59784e-02 4.44706e-08
6.00000e+00 6.00000e+00 -1.62172e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.35149e+03 0.00000e+00 1.59910e-02 3.17897e-08
6.00000e+00 7.00000e+00 -1.61657e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.36210e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60036e-02 2.38611e-08
6.00000e+00 8.00000e+00 -1.61069e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.37431e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60162e-02 1.85732e-08
6.00000e+00 9.00000e+00 -1.60406e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.38813e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60288e-02 1.48703e-08
6.00000e+00 1.00000e+01 -1.59668e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.40362e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60415e-02 1.21761e-08
6.00000e+00 1.10000e+01 -1.58854e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.42082e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60541e-02 1.01547e-08
6.00000e+00 1.20000e+01 -1.57965e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.43978e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60668e-02 8.59916e-09
6.00000e+00 1.30000e+01 -1.56999e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.46054e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60795e-02 7.37644e-09
6.00000e+00 1.40000e+01 -1.55956e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.48318e+03 0.00000e+00 1.60922e-02 6.39786e-09
6.00000e+00 1.50000e+01 -1.54836e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.50776e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61049e-02 5.60244e-09
6.00000e+00 1.60000e+01 -1.53636e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.53436e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61176e-02 4.94711e-09
6.00000e+00 1.70000e+01 -1.52358e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.56307e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61303e-02 4.40077e-09
6.00000e+00 1.80000e+01 -1.51000e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.59398e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61430e-02 3.94049e-09
6.00000e+00 1.90000e+01 -1.49560e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.62719e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61557e-02 3.54908e-09
6.00000e+00 2.00000e+01 -1.48038e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.66283e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61685e-02 3.21344e-09
6.00000e+00 2.10000e+01 -1.46433e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.70103e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61812e-02 2.92343e-09
6.00000e+00 2.20000e+01 -1.44743e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.74192e+03 0.00000e+00 1.61940e-02 2.67112e-09
6.00000e+00 2.30000e+01 -1.42967e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.78568e+03 0.00000e+00 1.62068e-02 2.45025e-09
6.00000e+00 2.40000e+01 -1.41104e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.83248e+03 0.00000e+00 1.62196e-02 2.25577e-09
6.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 -1.39153e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 7.88253e+03 0.00000e+00 1.62324e-02 2.08365e-09
6.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 nan nan 7.32003e+03 nan nan nan 2.08365e-09
7.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 5.17604e+03 5.17604e+03 1.59155e-02 0.00000e+00 [135, 189]
7.00000e+00 1.00000e+00 -1.63659e+07 5.17604e+03 7.32003e+03 5.17753e+03 5.17604e+03 1.59280e-02 6.64958e-07 [136, 190]
7.00000e+00 2.00000e+00 -1.63555e+07 1.55281e+04 7.32003e+03 5.18051e+03 5.17604e+03 1.59406e-02 2.21828e-07 [137, 191]
7.00000e+00 3.00000e+00 -1.63400e+07 3.10563e+04 7.32003e+03 5.18498e+03 5.17604e+03 1.59532e-02 1.11001e-07 [138, 192]
7.00000e+00 4.00000e+00 -1.63193e+07 5.17604e+04 7.32003e+03 5.19095e+03 5.17603e+03 1.59658e-02 6.66533e-08    ...
7.00000e+00 5.00000e+00 -1.62933e+07 7.76406e+04 7.32003e+03 5.19843e+03 5.17600e+03 1.59784e-02 4.44706e-08
7.00000e+00 6.00000e+00 -1.62622e+07 1.08697e+05 7.32003e+03 5.20744e+03 5.17596e+03 1.59910e-02 3.17897e-08
7.00000e+00 7.00000e+00 -1.62258e+07 1.44929e+05 7.32003e+03 5.21799e+03 5.17589e+03 1.60036e-02 2.38611e-08
7.00000e+00 8.00000e+00 -1.61841e+07 1.86336e+05 7.32003e+03 5.23010e+03 5.17578e+03 1.60162e-02 1.85732e-08
7.00000e+00 9.00000e+00 -1.61371e+07 2.32919e+05 7.32003e+03 5.24379e+03 5.17562e+03 1.60288e-02 1.48703e-08
7.00000e+00 1.00000e+01 -1.60847e+07 2.84676e+05 7.32003e+03 5.25909e+03 5.17540e+03 1.60415e-02 1.21761e-08
7.00000e+00 1.10000e+01 -1.60269e+07 3.41607e+05 7.32003e+03 5.27603e+03 5.17510e+03 1.60541e-02 1.01547e-08
7.00000e+00 1.20000e+01 -1.59637e+07 4.03711e+05 7.32003e+03 5.29464e+03 5.17471e+03 1.60668e-02 8.59916e-09
7.00000e+00 1.30000e+01 -1.58950e+07 4.70985e+05 7.32003e+03 5.31495e+03 5.17419e+03 1.60795e-02 7.37644e-09
7.00000e+00 1.40000e+01 -1.58208e+07 5.43429e+05 7.32003e+03 5.33701e+03 5.17354e+03 1.60922e-02 6.39786e-09
7.00000e+00 1.50000e+01 -1.57409e+07 6.21038e+05 7.32003e+03 5.36086e+03 5.17272e+03 1.61049e-02 5.60244e-09
7.00000e+00 1.60000e+01 -1.56553e+07 7.03810e+05 7.32003e+03 5.38654e+03 5.17171e+03 1.61176e-02 4.94711e-09
7.00000e+00 1.70000e+01 -1.55640e+07 7.91739e+05 7.32003e+03 5.41410e+03 5.17047e+03 1.61303e-02 4.40077e-09
7.00000e+00 1.80000e+01 -1.54668e+07 8.84821e+05 7.32003e+03 5.44360e+03 5.16897e+03 1.61430e-02 3.94049e-09
7.00000e+00 1.90000e+01 -1.53637e+07 9.83048e+05 7.32003e+03 5.47510e+03 5.16716e+03 1.61557e-02 3.54908e-09
7.00000e+00 2.00000e+01 -1.52545e+07 1.08641e+06 7.32003e+03 5.50867e+03 5.16502e+03 1.61685e-02 3.21344e-09
7.00000e+00 2.10000e+01 -1.51392e+07 1.19491e+06 7.32003e+03 5.54437e+03 5.16247e+03 1.61812e-02 2.92343e-09
7.00000e+00 2.20000e+01 -1.50177e+07 1.30851e+06 7.32003e+03 5.58227e+03 5.15948e+03 1.61940e-02 2.67112e-09
7.00000e+00 2.30000e+01 -1.48897e+07 1.42722e+06 7.32003e+03 5.62246e+03 5.15598e+03 1.62068e-02 2.45025e-09
7.00000e+00 2.40000e+01 -1.47553e+07 1.55101e+06 7.32003e+03 5.66503e+03 5.15190e+03 1.62196e-02 2.25577e-09
7.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 -1.46142e+07 1.67987e+06 7.32003e+03 5.71005e+03 5.14717e+03 1.62324e-02 2.08365e-09
7.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 nan nan 7.32003e+03 nan nan nan 2.08365e-09
8.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 0.00000e+00 7.32003e+03 4.48222e-13 7.32003e+03 1.59155e-02 0.00000e+00
8.00000e+00 1.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 7.32003e+03 7.32003e+03 1.48721e+00 7.32003e+03 1.59280e-02 6.64958e-07
8.00000e+00 2.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 2.19601e+04 7.32003e+03 4.46162e+00 7.32003e+03 1.59406e-02 2.21828e-07
8.00000e+00 3.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 4.39202e+04 7.32003e+03 8.92323e+00 7.32002e+03 1.59532e-02 1.11001e-07
8.00000e+00 4.00000e+00 -1.63710e+07 7.32003e+04 7.32003e+03 1.48720e+01 7.32001e+03 1.59658e-02 6.66533e-08
8.00000e+00 5.00000e+00 -1.63710e+07 1.09800e+05 7.32003e+03 2.23078e+01 7.31997e+03 1.59784e-02 4.44706e-08
8.00000e+00 6.00000e+00 -1.63709e+07 1.53720e+05 7.32003e+03 3.12306e+01 7.31991e+03 1.59910e-02 3.17897e-08
8.00000e+00 7.00000e+00 -1.63707e+07 2.04960e+05 7.32003e+03 4.16399e+01 7.31981e+03 1.60036e-02 2.38610e-08
8.00000e+00 8.00000e+00 -1.63704e+07 2.63519e+05 7.32003e+03 5.35353e+01 7.31967e+03 1.60162e-02 1.85731e-08
8.00000e+00 9.00000e+00 -1.63700e+07 3.29397e+05 7.32003e+03 6.69160e+01 7.31945e+03 1.60288e-02 1.48701e-08
8.00000e+00 1.00000e+01 -1.63694e+07 4.02593e+05 7.32003e+03 8.17810e+01 7.31915e+03 1.60415e-02 1.21759e-08
8.00000e+00 1.10000e+01 -1.63686e+07 4.83106e+05 7.32003e+03 9.81288e+01 7.31875e+03 1.60541e-02 1.01544e-08
8.00000e+00 1.20000e+01 -1.63675e+07 5.70934e+05 7.32003e+03 1.15957e+02 7.31822e+03 1.60668e-02 8.59875e-09
8.00000e+00 1.30000e+01 -1.63661e+07 6.66076e+05 7.32003e+03 1.35264e+02 7.31755e+03 1.60795e-02 7.37594e-09
8.00000e+00 1.40000e+01 -1.63644e+07 7.68527e+05 7.32003e+03 1.56046e+02 7.31670e+03 1.60922e-02 6.39726e-09
8.00000e+00 1.50000e+01 -1.63622e+07 8.78286e+05 7.32003e+03 1.78299e+02 7.31566e+03 1.61049e-02 5.60172e-09
8.00000e+00 1.60000e+01 -1.63595e+07 9.95346e+05 7.32003e+03 2.02017e+02 7.31439e+03 1.61176e-02 4.94627e-09
8.00000e+00 1.70000e+01 -1.63563e+07 1.11970e+06 7.32003e+03 2.27195e+02 7.31285e+03 1.61303e-02 4.39980e-09
8.00000e+00 1.80000e+01 -1.63525e+07 1.25135e+06 7.32003e+03 2.53826e+02 7.31103e+03 1.61430e-02 3.93939e-09
8.00000e+00 1.90000e+01 -1.63479e+07 1.39028e+06 7.32003e+03 2.81900e+02 7.30888e+03 1.61557e-02 3.54783e-09
8.00000e+00 2.00000e+01 -1.63426e+07 1.53648e+06 7.32003e+03 3.11408e+02 7.30637e+03 1.61685e-02 3.21203e-09
8.00000e+00 2.10000e+01 -1.63364e+07 1.68995e+06 7.32003e+03 3.42337e+02 7.30346e+03 1.61812e-02 2.92186e-09
8.00000e+00 2.20000e+01 -1.63292e+07 1.85066e+06 7.32003e+03 3.74675e+02 7.30012e+03 1.61940e-02 2.66939e-09
8.00000e+00 2.30000e+01 -1.63210e+07 2.01861e+06 7.32003e+03 4.08404e+02 7.29630e+03 1.62068e-02 2.44833e-09
8.00000e+00 2.40000e+01 -1.63116e+07 2.19377e+06 7.32003e+03 4.43508e+02 7.29196e+03 1.62196e-02 2.25368e-09
8.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 -1.63009e+07 2.37613e+06 7.32003e+03 4.79966e+02 7.28705e+03 1.62324e-02 2.08136e-09
8.00000e+00 2.50000e+01 nan nan 7.32003e+03 nan nan nan 2.08136e-09
...
```

Comment: Can you please give an example to explain what you have and what you want? Also, should that `create_idxs` have `return` instead of `self.`? (I'm guessing this is part of a class that you edited for the post.)

Comment: @jared Example up - Yes this is part of a class - i can adapt it if the answer has all references to `self` removed

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand what you're looking for. I'll have to think about how to do this with pure numpy functions, but if you have a very large dataset, it may not be efficient because I think you'll have to broadcast. How many times do you need to do this? If you do it a lot, you might benefit from using Numba.

Comment: @jared the len of the dataset could be greater than 1mil so that by 8 columns is 8mil elements? This operation is only needed once per method call so I wouldn't have much interest in Numba unless there is no speedup available via numpy

Comment: @jared Good to know that it isn't trivial - I was kicking myself thinking it shouldn't be that hard

Comment: Maybe there is a better way to do it using Numpy. Someone else might write an answer if they know one. I still have a lot to learn about Numpy.

Comment: @jared Same - everywhere I go, I read "don't use for-loops with NumPy" but it seems like there are just some operations that can't be done with pure NumPy AFAICT

Comment: It's true, the whole point of using numpy is to push the loops from Python to a lower-level language (i.e. C). But yes, it is sometimes not possible to avoid loops. Numba is useful in those cases.

Comment: The problem is, you don't want to search each of 1 mil rows on every row. You need to somehow limit the search space. How many unique values are in this 2nd and 4th position?

Comment: @AndrejKesely there could be up to 780 unique values in the 2nd position and up to 50 unique values in the 4th position. The values in the 1st position are all completely unique (and basically serve as an index that starts at 1). Maybe it's worth noting that that is what I do in my for-loop - loop through these unique values in the 2nd/4th position to cut the "master" array to size, then do the broadcasting.

Comment: I propose to split the whole array according to value of 2nd position, then on every row you need to search ~1200 values (if you sort the values, you can even use binary search on the value on 4th position)

Comment: @AndrejKesely Would I then need to loop through the fragments created by the split or is there a numpythonic way to handle the split and required logic having added a new dimension?

Comment: @SterlingButters You can create a dictionary where keys are values on 2nd position and values are numpy arrays (best to sort these arrays by value on 4th position, to ease the search).

Comment: @AndrejKesely That still seems kind of "loopy" to me. I feel like I need to take advantage of the fact that the first column is unique outside of t (that is, there could be up to 780 rows with identical values in the first column). If I could sort by the second column, then look at the first and notice that the closest values in the first column already correspond to adjacent rows then I just need to eliminate the cases where adjacent rows don't meet the condition of matching 2nd/4th columns. Maybe I'm getting somewhere?

Comment: @SterlingButters I've posted an answer how you can split the array + compute the indices.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, you can split the array by the value in second column (`[1]`) and then compute the indices:

```py
# note you don't need `t` here:
def query_trks(FULL, trk, v, N):
    filt = np.where(FULL[:, 4] == v)[0]
    trks = FULL[filt, 0]
    idxs = np.abs(trks[:, None] - trks).argsort(axis=0)[:N]
    return FULL[idxs.T.astype(int), -1]  # return original indices that are stored in the last column


N = 2
arr = np.loadtxt("data.txt")

# add original index
arr = np.c_[arr, np.arange(len(arr))]

# sort arr by 2nd value:
arr = arr[arr[:, 1].argsort()]

# split the array by 2nd value
splitted_array = np.split(arr, np.unique(arr[:, 1], return_index=True)[1][1:])

columns_to_add = np.concatenate(
    [query_trks(a, a[:, 0], a[:, 4], N) for a in splitted_array]
)

# add back computed indices to arr
arr = np.c_[arr, columns_to_add]

# sort arr back (by the original index)
arr = arr[arr[:, -N - 1].argsort()]

print(arr)
```

Prints (the computed indices are in the last N columns):

```
[[ 1.00000e+00  0.00000e+00 -1.63711e+07 ...  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00
   2.70000e+01]
 [ 1.00000e+00  1.00000e+00 -1.63687e+07 ...  1.00000e+00  1.00000e+00
   2.80000e+01]
 [ 1.00000e+00  2.00000e+00 -1.63639e+07 ...  2.00000e+00  2.00000e+00
   2.90000e+01]

...
```

Comment: hmmmm this isn't giving the expected result. When doing a quick test: 
`for i in range(len(FULL))[1000:1500]:
            print(FULL[i,0], FULL[columns_to_add[i].astype(int), 0])` should return values that all within 2 of each other. I.e. this printed stuff like: ```14.0 [160.0 67.0]
364.0 [221.0 390.0]
371.0 [395.0 425.0]
324.0 [442.0 416.0]
16.0 [119.0 67.0]``` when I expected something like ```[26.0 25.0 27.0]
[27.0 28.0 26.0]
[28.0 29.0 27.0]
[29.0 30.0 28.0]
[30.0 31.0 29.0]
[31.0 32.0 30.0]
[32.0 33.0 31.0]``` (showing how values are all within 2)

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work by appropriately sorting the data and noting the indices where values in column 2 or 4 change and then appropriately backtracking or forwardtracking from these indices:

```
    ii = np.lexsort((FULL[:,1], FULL[:,4], FULL[:,0])[::-1])
    TEST = FULL[ii]
    TEST = TEST[TEST[:,2]!=None]

    # Now that sorted, identify inflections for v or t 
    infx_t = np.where(TEST[:-1,1] != TEST[1:,1])[0]
    infx_v = np.where(TEST[:-1,4] != TEST[1:,4])[0]
    infx_c = np.unique(np.hstack(([0], infx_t, infx_v))) # Turns out computation of infx might acutally be unnecessary (len(infx_v) == len(infx_c))

    # Upper side of inflection will be -2 and -1 (upper is the infx point itself - lower would be +1)
    # Lower side of inflection will be +2 and +1
    # Otherwise -1 and +1 
    idxs = np.arange(len(TEST))
    n_idxs = np.column_stack((idxs-1, idxs+1))  
    n_idxs[infx_c]   = infx_c[:,None] - np.arange(1,3)
    n_idxs[infx_c+1] = infx_c[:,None] + np.arange(2,4)
    n_idxs[-1] = len(n_idxs) - np.arange(2,4)              # Just manually fix last entry
    n_idxs = np.column_stack((idxs, n_idxs))
```

Granted, this solution is parametrized in `N` but should be relatively easy for me to change the `np.arange`s to do so